# Joomla redirects to live version

Tags: redirect, joomla

Hi I've searched a lot right now (since monday...) and still can't find the problem.
I have copied the live version of a Joomla installation to my local machine for development (I haven't set up the live version and it's a bunch of cr*p).
I set up the db, changed the config, but as soon as I try to open localhost/project instead I'm redirected to project.tld.

I've searched all files and the whole DB for project.tld and can't find anything which says "redirect to project.tld".

Also removed the .htaccess, but still I'm redirected. Can't find anything in templates or elsewhere.

Any idea what may cause this?
I think it's some Addon / Plugin whatever, but can't figure out which one and why.

Yours
iNaD

Comment: I'm redirected to project.tld. ?? means??

Comment: What I'm saying. I open localhost/project in my browser (to access the local site, because who wants to develop on a live system?), but instead that joomla shows up, it redirects me to the joomla @ project.tld

Comment: is it only with this project or all at your local host?

Comment: Only for this project. As far as I know Joomla should handle it right without any configuration, but probably some plugin redirects me to the live version. As I have written even without the htaccess I'm redirected, so it's not a rewrite rule :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it works right now. I've disabled the com_redirect component in the db (which I've already done about 10 times...) and after enabling it again, the site loaded.

Sometimes I don't understand Joomla. I nearly disabled every extension and now after doing the same procedure again it works.

For anyone else having this problem: Be sure you have disabled extenstions like "Canonicalization", some SEO and / or RSS extensions etc. As I've read now they also cause those redirects to old / wrong URLs.

Thanks anyway swapnesh for trying to help me. I nearly became desperate.

Comment: iNaD its good to see you responded back to ur question +1 ..for sharing :)

Comment: seen this issue before with other peoples sites but never looked into what the problem could be. +1 for the info ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) I still don't know what exactly the problem was, but after those little tricks it worked.
I hope it'll help people with the same problem.